# I am unable to push a git repository to my github account after the latest macbook system update

Tags: git, github

After updating my laptop (MacBook Air) I am unable to push my repository to git. Everything works fine till the last moment when I have to push to the -u origin main.
I don't know if it helps but I haven't run into problems while pulling and cloning.
This is what I get when I try to push, it doesn't give an error, it just stays that way.

```
Enumerating objects: 12, done.
Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.37 MiB | 426.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases it wont be an issue so you just have to wait a little longer until it is complete. Since you are able to pull and fetch I don't see an access issue but it will throw an error if you are lacking necessary write permissions.

Alternatively to solve this problem you can try increasing the post buffer using the below command in your terminal

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

and set this

```
git config --global sendpack.sideband false
```

Finally make a local commit and try pushing it again.